# Karma-Jasmine Testing register form in Angular template driven forms

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I'm very new to Angular. I'm trying to do Jasmine testing on template-driven forms but I got stuck.

This is my **.html** file

```html
<form name="Registerform" #Registerform="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="registerUser()" class="form">
            <div class="form-header">
                <h1 style="text-align: center;font-weight: bold; ">Register</h1>
            </div>
            <small class="text-danger">{{msg}}</small>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter email" name="email"
                        [(ngModel)]="user.emailId" required pattern="^[a-zA-Z0-9+_.-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+$" #email="ngModel"
                        [class.is-invalid]="email.invalid && email.touched">
                    <!--<small class="text-danger" [class.d-none]="email.valid || email.untouched">Email Id is required
                field</small>-->

                    <div *ngIf="email.errors && (email.invalid && email.touched)">
                        <small class="text-danger" *ngIf="email.errors.required">Email Id is required</small>
                        <small class="text-danger" *ngIf="email.errors.pattern">Enter the valid valid email id</small>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <button [disabled]=" Registerform.form.invalid" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Register</button>
            <small class="float-right" [routerLink]="['/login']">Having an Account ? <a href="/login">Login</a>
                here</small>
        </form>
```

This is **.ts** file

```js
export class RegisterComponent implements OnInit {
user = new User();
  msg = "";
  roles: any = ['Admin', 'Employee'];
  constructor(private _service: RegistrationService, private _router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  radioChangedHandler(event: any) {
    this.user.role = event.target.value;
  }

  registerUser() {

    this._service.registerUserFromRemote(this.user).subscribe(
      data => {
        console.log("response received");
        this.msg = "Registration Successful"
        this._router.navigate(['/login']);
      },
      error => {
        console.log("exception occured")
        // this.msg = error.error();
      }
    )

  }
}
```

This is User Class

```js
export class User {
    id: number | undefined;
    emailId: string | undefined;
    userName: string | undefined;
    password: string | undefined;
    cpassword: string | undefined;
    role: string | undefined;
    walletAmt: number | undefined;
    constructor() { }

}
```

I have tried to make an test case for component and email.But i'm getting "no expectation" error.

This is my .spec file

```js
it('email should be correct', async () => {

        fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
            let email = component.user.emailId;
            email = "abc@gmail.com";
            expect(email).toBeTruthy();
            
            
        });

    })
    it('email should be false', async () => {
        fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
            let email = component.user.emailId;
            let val = component.registerUser()
            email = '';

            expect(email).toBeFalsy();
        });
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

the expectations are inside unreachable code. `then` callback with such approach would be executed after the test is finished. You can leverage very convenient `await` syntax to make it reachable.

```js
it('email should be correct', async () => {
   await fixture.whenStable();

   let email = component.user.emailId;
   expect(email).toBeTruthy();
})
    
it('email should be false', async () => {
   await fixture.whenStable();

   let val = component.registerUser()
   let email = component.user.emailId;
   expect(email).toBeFalsy();
})
```

While looking into the test code it is not that easy to grasp what is tested.

PS: template-driven forms are not playing well with unit tests. And in general, this approach is less powerful than reactive forms. I would rather avoid attempts to cover those with tests and invest time in learning reactive forms.